# How to make a trigger for create_view

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I need to make a trigger about who and when created a view. I have some groundwork about it.[image: Code]. So, when some user is running a script for create view, trigger is crushing because this user doesn't have a permission to insert. [image: Execute as] When I use trigger with EXECUTE AS OWNER, there is a problem with it. Problem - OWNER is not a valid parameter for EXECUTE AS in the context of server and database level triggers.

Comment: EXECUTE AS OWNER is not applicable here because database-level triggers don't have an owner (this is related to why you can't create a database-level trigger in the scope of a specific schema).

Answer (score 4):

Use `execute as self`

```
create or alter trigger check_view 
on database
with execute as self
for create_view
as . . .
```

or `execute as 'dbo'`

```
create or alter trigger check_view 
on database
with execute as 'dbo'
for create_view
as . . .
```